# While training Model on Google Colab, should I remain connected?

Tags: google-colaboratory, object-detection, training-data, darknet, custom-training

Do I need to remain connected with Colab and the internet when training a dataset model (Darknet) for Object detection on Google Colab? As the training is going on Colab and connected to my drive, here Weight files will be saved on my google drive folder. So, can I disconnect my internet and exit colab?

This is the last screen shown when I started my training process on COLAB and now I am waiting for my weight files to be saved in my drive:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You absolutely must remain connected to colab for ensuring that your code continues to run. Just because your weight files are being saved to Google Drive does not mean that you can disconnect/close the browser and it will continue to run. Keep in mind that Google Drive is just mounted for the sake of storage space and is not an alternative to an active Colab session.

However, if your Colab session gets disconnected suddenly due to internet/server issues, it'll automatically try to reconnect after a "short" while and continue execution from the interruption point (if you're back online). However, if the time to start after the timeout is too long, you have to run all cells from the start and it can't continue it's most recent operation.

Note that this does not apply if you have exhausted the permitted usage limit for a give time (supposed to be 12 hrs). In this case, you may have to wait for many hours before being allowed to use Colab again