# Colab notebook execution fails if internet is down. How to prevent this?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, grid-search

I am running a XGB grid search on Colab python notebook. It might take 3-4 hrs for the data I have. The colab notebook that I am running gets interrupted if my internet is down and it starts execution once network is back. Does this mean it is resuming and will print the output after execution or the output is lost?

How can I prevent colab notebook from disconnecting?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66797297/while-training-model-on-google-colab-should-i-remain-connected